# Anyone run into issues with this.datasource in application.cfc

Tags: coldfusion, application.cfc

This is odd and undoubtedly just another case of my embarrassingly limited capacity for problem solving causing issues BUT - We have an API that we've been using since October of 2012.  Changes are VERY few and far between (as in maybe, two or three tweaks total).

About 3 months ago is APPEARS as though this.datasource in application.cfc stopped being recognized.  The server was reporting this.datasource = ''.

Does anyone have any experience with this or insight into the circumstances under which this could happen?  I'm more than happy to wear the dunce hat on this one but it has nme a bit emotionally bedraggled and I just 'gotta know'...my ninja theory isn't getting much traction in the office.

Comment: I've had issues in the past that when an error occurs, the datasource value in the application.cfm gets wiped out.  Could be the same thing?

Comment: Interesting. Double check that something is not overwriting it. For example, an application.cfc file in a subfolder, or an application.cfc file elswhere with the same "this.name" that has a blank datasource (name must be unique) or perhaps an explicit cfset of application.datasource to an empty string. Those are the things that come to mind.

Comment: Is `this.datasource` set in a conditional way? Like logic to decide between dev/prod. If so, post that logic or how that var is being set. I would also look for any files named application.cfc or application.cfm ANYWHERE in your application. Also, is `this.datasource` being set AFTER it's being used in the application somewhere?

Comment: ya I had this before. I have since stopped using this 'feature'.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues before. To fix it I moved `<cfset this.datasource = "whatever" />` to the `OnApplicationStart` function in application.cfc.
After you do so, remember to reinit the application.

Comment: There are 2 problems here. Firstly, it should be "the OnApplicationStart function in Application.cfc". Secondly, as I mentioned earlier, it is poor design to define an application-wide variable in the _this_ scope of Application.cfc. Strictly speaking, _this_ refers to an instance of Application.cfc. The correct scope for application-wide variables is `application.x`. I realize entrenched habits die hard and some might not like to hear the news.

Comment: If you use this.datasource you don't have to specify the datasource in `cfquery`.

Comment: Indeed, Jules. But that was not always the case in older versions of Coldfusion.

Answer (score -1):

Strictly speaking, the *this* scope in Application.cfc refers to fields that are specific to the application file itself. For example, sessionTimeout, applicationTimeout, loginStorage and so on. You may loosely interpret them as the application's meta data. Fields defined with *this* are therefore not meant to be accessed elsewhere in the application.

Datasource is the kind of property that refers to the application. You should therefore define it in onApplicationStart as:

```
application.datasource
```

Comment: It bears repeating: the _this_ scope in Application.cfc does not necessarily apply application-wide!